# Debian + Ruby1.9 problem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian

I installed ruby 1.9.1 on my Debian Squeeze. After that I tried to install ruby gems, but

```
aptitude why-not rubygems1.9.1
i   ruby1.9.1 Conflicts rubygems1.9.1
```

I have /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ in my filesystem, but I havn't any binary file like rubygems1.9.1 or gems. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the `gem1.9.1` command anyway. The reason `ruby1.9.1` conflicts with `rubygems1.9.1` is because rubygems has been integrated into the `ruby1.9.1` package.